# Webpack hot module replacement on docker/macOS recompile error

Tags: macos, docker, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I am using docker in my dev environment with hot module replacement on macOS. I can run my app successfully and when changing files webpack hot reloading actually picks up the change. However, the recompile always fails at this step with the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

**webpack.config**

This is my webpack configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
        //publicPath: '/'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            camelCase: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'dist/index.html',
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        contentBase: './dist',
        port: 8080,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        hot: true
    },
    watchOptions: { poll: true }
};
```

**package.json**

My package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-prop-types": "^0.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.1"
  }
}
```

**executed command to run**

To run the app I use the following command line. It creates a volume synced with docker and launches the dev server with the "start" command, executing *webpack-dev-server*. I can access and use the app but not hot reload without above error message.

```
docker run --rm -i -t -v /Path/to/folder:/app -p 8080:8080 jmfirth/webpack yarn start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Issue has been fixed by now.

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6983) and its discussion this seems to be an issue with the latest webpack-dev-servers hot module in combination with webpack 4.5.0.

The problem has been solved by downgrading webpack-dev-server to version 3.0.0 but there is still an [open issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1369) in the webpack-dev-server repository.